# Asp.net exception thread was being aborted

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have aspx page **(web from)**. That page contains some data fields and submit button.

Once user click on submit button `WCF service` method will get called from the code behind.
WCF service will do some DB manipulations and sometimes it will take nearly 3-4 mins to completed and send the result to the page.

Since it will get more time aspx page gives an exception **System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted**

What do I need to do in order to fix this??

My service binding is like below

```
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_IDbHelperService" closeTimeout="10:01:00"
openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="10:01:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00"
maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem awhile back.  The thread aborted exception you are receiving is most likely due to an error occurring on the WCF side and that exception is not being sent back to the client.  I'd recommend setting up logging within the WCF service to find out what's really going on and be sure to set the [IncludeExceptionDetailsInFault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx) property to true (during development, set to false when releasing).  I'd also recommend reading [Fault Handling in WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx).

Comment: WCF also maintained by me and I am logging every exception triggered. When I check the logs I cannot find any exception.

Comment: I was able to fix my issue by increasing timeout value `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600"/>`. Thanks for your kind attention to my issue